# Kotlin is the Open keyword a visibility modifier?

Tags: kotlin, visibility

I'm new at Kotlin and I'm reading the [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#packages) official documentation, it states the 4 differents visibility modifiers (public, private, internal, protected) furthermore it's also using the keyword OPEN to express that a class can be extended (that is its purpose). My question is, can OPEN be considered as a Visibility Modifier?

Comment: No, it doesn’t impact visibility. It’s an inheritance modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `open` is not a visibility modifier, as it does not affect visibility at all.

Instead, `open` affects if classes or methods can be extended/overridden and is the opposite of javas `final` in these cases.